# Publish different APKs with the same project with Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a base project and I want to create multiple Apps from it. Is a project that load data depending on a variable on the Strings.xml.

I just want to publish the same application like three different, the first one has a certain value, the second another, etc...

I'm trying to use the base project as a Library and use it into other three projects but I'm not being able to run the app.

This is what I did until now...:

Added the Library in the App Path.

Added the 'use' in the Manifest.

```
 <uses-library 
        android:name="com.example.dioniso"
        android:required="true"/>
```

Added the main activity of the library to the project.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.dioniso.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and I'm getting:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

but I don't have any error on the Problems tab... what can I do? I'm lost.

EDIT1:

I've removed the  and now I can install the APP, but I'm getting this error now:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sime.baccuscartaelecminister/com.example.dioniso.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This happens when I'm calling to a function that is out of the 'com.example.dioniso' package but it's into the project.

Comment: The problem comes up because for external jars its not required to declare library on manifest... try after deleting uses-library

Comment: Thanks!!! I feel like I'm one step closer. Now I'm getting another error, I'll add to the post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your library project does not get exported into the APK file.

try to removed it from the Java build path and added is an Android library via "Properties -> Android -> Add..."

Answer (score 0):

For the Library Project ,you have to go to Properties->Android and Select Is Library as shown below:

[image]

Now for the projects that are using your library ,add the library to it Properties->Android->Add.See the Image below[image]